# Download csv in R from web

Tags: html, r, screen-scraping

I would like to download a csv from a web page. My code is the following:

```
url<-"https://rondasmexico.gob.mx/esp/contratos/cnh-r01-l01-a22015/?tab=11#"

url<-read_html(url)

links=url %>% html_nodes("#p11-btnDownload-datos") %>% html_attr("href")

download.file(url=links[1],destfile = "cnh-r01-l01-a22015.csv")
```

At the end I get the following answer:

```
"scheme not supported in URL '#'
```

Comment: Look at `links` and see that it is a vector, length 1, and that one string is `"#"` (that's the whole URL.

Comment: If you look before extracting the `"href"` attribute, you see `<a id="p11-btnDownload-datos" class="btn btn-default" href="#">Descarga CSV</a>`, which reinforces the fact that this is not a normal anchor.